# error tapestry using data gridsource 2

Tags: java, datagrid, error-handling, tapestry

Continuing [tutorial](http://www.packtpub.com/article/tapestry-5-advanced-components) I have came across an error.
previous problem seems to be [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220936/tapestry-using-data-gridsource).

tutorial says:
To make use of the created CelebritySource, add the following method to the ShowAll page class:

```
public GridDataSource getCelebritySource()
{
return new CelebritySource(dataSource);
}
```

Then change the source parameter of the Grid component in ShowAll.tml template:

```
<t:grid t:source="celebritySource" rowsPerPage="5"
row="celebrity" t:model="model">
```

Run the application. Log in to view the ShowAll page, and as soon as the table with celebrities is displayed, you should see the following output:

Preparing selection.
Index from 0 to 4
Property name is: null
Sorting order ascending: true
Getting value for row 0
Getting value for row 1
Getting value for row 2
Getting value for row 3
Getting value for row 4

page has error:

> An unexpected application exception has occurred.
>
> Exception assembling root component of page ShowAll: Could not convert
>   'model' into a component parameter binding: Exception generating
>   conduit for expression 'model': Class
>   org.apache.tapestry.pages.ShowAll does not contain a property (or
>   public field) named 'model'.

After deleteing t:model="model" from t:grid

page has error:

> An unexpected application exception has occurred.
>
> Render queue error in SetupRender[ShowAll:grid]: Index: 0

Anyone out there had this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the example was missing a bit of code. Try adding the following to the page `ShowAll.java`:

```
@Inject
private BeanModelSource beanModelSource;

@Inject
private Messages messages;

public BeanModel<Celebrity> getModel() {
  return beanModelSource.createDisplayModel(Celebrity.class, messages);
}
```

From the [T5 Grid Component Ref](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.html):

> The model used to identify the properties to be presented and the order of presentation.

The above should create you a default BeanModel, based on public methods and properties.

Comment: That improved the solution.
however now its displaying same error as when i deleted the t:model="model" from t:grid page has error: > An unexpected application exception has occurred.
> > Render queue error in SetupRender[ShowAll:grid]: Index: 0